# Deriving an equation from coordinate points?

Tags: calculus

Find an equation in x, y, z for the plane that
passes through the given points.

$P_1(1, 0, 1), P_2(2, 1, 0), P_3(1, 1, 1).$

I know how to look at these problems and label them as equations for the first step.

$P_1: i+k$

$P_2:2i+j+0$

$P_3: i+j+k$

How does one manipulate these equations to solve the answer. I could try completing the square or cross product $a \times b$ or dot product $a\cdot b$ but I am unsure if that will yield any correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equation for the plane is one of the form $$Ax+By+Cz=D$$
being $A,B,C$ and $D$ constants, since $(1,0,1)$, $(2,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ lies in the plane we have the system of equations
\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
A&+&&+&C&=&D\\
2A&+&B&&&=&D\\
A&+&B&+&C&=&D
\end{array}
By subtracting the  first from the third equation we get $B=0$, and according to the second one it follows $A=D/2$, and plugging this into the first we have $C=D/2$. By taking $D=2$, an equation for the plane is found:
$$x+z=2$$

Comment: Would it not be D/2+C=D? which get you C=2?

Comment: \begin{align}
D/2+C&=D\\
\implies C&=D-D/2\\
\implies C&=D/2
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry I have a cold today I was not thinking straight.

Comment: Why is D = 2? Also why is it x+z = 2?

Comment: We need an equation for the plane, and it will work with any $D$, I took $D=2$ cause this give us the simplest one. But you can use $D=1$ or $D=5$, an so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Let General equation of plane be $ax+by+cz+d = 0\;,$ Then equation of plane passes through

The point $P(1,0,1)$ is $$a(x-1)+b(y-0)+c(z-1) = 0..........(1)$$

Now plane also passes through $Q(2,1,0)\;,$ So Put $x=2,y=1,z=0\;,$ We get

$$a(2-1)+b(1-0)+c(0-1) = 0.........(2)$$

Now Now plane also passes through $Q(1,1,1)\;,$ So Put $x=2,y=1,z=0\;\bf{in \; (1)\;,}$ We get

$$a(1-1)+b(1-0)+c(1-1) = 0........(3)$$

Now Eliminating $a,b$ and $c$ from these $3$ equations and get an equation of plane

We can also eliminate $a,b$ and $c$ as

$$\displaystyle \begin{vmatrix}
 x-1& y & z-1\\ 
 1& 1& -1\\ 
 0& 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=0\Rightarrow -1\left[(1-x)+1-z\right] = 0\Rightarrow x+z-2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors in the plane are

$$\vec a = P_2-P_1 = (1, 1, -1)$$

$$\vec b = P_3-P_1 = (0, 1, 0)$$

The plane will have normal vector $\vec a \times\vec b$ . The equation can be fixed by requiring that the plane passes through any one of the three points $P_1, P_2 \text{ or }P_3$

so if $\vec a \times\vec b = (c,d,e)$ then the equation of the plane would be ..

$$ cx + dy + ez = c(1)+d(0)+e(1) $$

using the point $P_1$ 
It doesn't matter which point you use because if you have done it correctly then

$$ c(1)+d(0)+e(1) =c(2)+d(1)+e(0)=c(1)+d(1)+e(1) $$